Airflow custom back fill Between start and end dates
I am looking for solution in airflow to schedule backfill run's between custom start date and end date. I don't have access to airflow API using CLI. I can use airflow UI as well trigger dag with Config. Using Config route how can I pass start_date, end_date to DAG & trigger it. Any help or direction on this will be appreciated. We are on airflow 2.xx version
